# Помогите понять логику динамического параметра, который передается при запросе к API сайта

Tags: python-3.x, json, requests

На сайте https://www.temu.com/ товары динамические подгружаются путем запроса к API и возвращаются в формате JSON. При запросе передаются обязательные параметры типа offset, id и среди них есть параметр anti-content, который динамически меняется при новом или повторном запросе. То есть один этот параметр не подходит для следующего запроса и доступ к API прекращается. Никак не могу понять логику, как реализовать с помощью python-requests эти запросы. Или же как понять откуда генерируется этот anti-content, чтобы при каждом новом запросе подставлять в параметр нужное значение.

Пробовал найти что-то в других get-post запросах отправленных на сервер, думал в ответе генерируется что-то похожее, но пока безуспешно
[image: Скриншот параметра]

Comment: Подозреваю что смысл этого параметра как раз в защите от вас.

Comment: Это как раз защита от парсинга. Вероятней всего формируется этот параметр где-то на клиентской стороне.  Из каких-то параметров, которые отдает бекенд. Вряд ли тут будет простой ответ. Надо анализировать сайт и все его JS скрипты.

Comment: при открытии страницы загружаются 6 скриптов, не меняются и не появляются новые, когда при скроллинге динамически подгружаются товары. Только отправляются пост запросы к API и на изображения

Comment: Любой такой запрос можно повторить в Postman один раз, т.е. эти ключи действуют дважды, потом уже не откликаются. Из того что я успел посмотреть в запросах и JS коде есть множественные запросы до, в них прилетают более мелкие ключи. `anti_content` встречается всего в двух скриптах, в основном в biz, там завязан на `useAntiTokenKey`, который берётся из events `e.sent`. В общем, в minified js всё это трейсить без бутылки не получится принцип примерно как у двуфакторки, на основе мелкого ключа считается этот, такой же алгоритм на сервере, если приходит валидный, то сервер отвечает.

Comment: да видимо тут так просто данные не получишь